# AWS API Gateway with JWT tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Currently I'm developing a Desktop C# based-app using the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authorization. So I'm getting the Client Access and the Refresh Token without any problem.

So, the OAuth 2.0 is saying that we need the Access-Token to retrieve the data from my services. However after reading the Amazon Documentation about it, I'm completely confused because they are using another way of doing it(Access-keys), Generating Access-Keys and temporary Keys and other ways.

Why do we need then the Access-Token? 
Is there any another way of doing it, using the Access-Token and without having to deal with the amazon SDKs??

Thanks

Comment: where is this `client access` described in Cognito? What are you trying to achieve? Are there some APIs you need to access? or your application needs access to AWS resources?

Comment: "I'm getting the Client Access and the Refresh Token without any problem" : I mean I'm getting the access Token and the refresh token! I'm trying to retrieve data from some resources without using the AWS SDKs.

Comment: Ok. What is front-ending those resources? If these resources are behing an `apigateway`, you can use `Cognito user pool` authorizer with `apigateway`. Integration for that exists - all you need to do is configure. So it's important to know where your resources exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that, there are other ways of calling AWS services, i.e Access-keys etc. It is upto you on how you want to use Cognito. You can use it for either of the following:

**Authentication** only -> verify the user is indeed who they identify themselves to be. You can do this by simply checking whether Cognito provided tokens. After that you can ignore the tokens in your application and proceed with the normal way of accessing AWS resources.

The other option is **Authorization** -> this is more than just authentication. This is better suited in scenarios when not all users of your application have the same kind of privilege. Maybe some users can access data in a S3 bucket, while other users cannot, etc. For this purpose, you need to set up IAM Roles and policies and have your application to use the access tokens instead of keys. If you have another way of handling authorization, then don't go for Cognito one.

Comment: Thanks @Deepthi for your answer! The main problem is that I couldn't find how to make the application use the access tokens instead of keys. All I was able to find in the Amazon documentation was using the key tokens to get the data! Can you provide me with a Link? I'll be gratefull. Thanks

Comment: @AliBenYedder For that you need to use Cognito Identiy Pool. You can find documentation here for that: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html

Comment: The link that you've provided is treating it with the SDks. I'm not implementing the SDKs. I took another way and tried to authenticate using Login With Amazon and once receiving an Access Token I've trying to send it to STS to get the credentials. The STS is returning 400 Bad Request : Provided Token is not a Login With Amazon token.